# PyQt context menu

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4

I'm adding a contextmenu to a QTableWidget dynamically:

```
playlistContenxt = QAction("Add to %s" % (currentItem.text()), self.musicTable)
playlistContenxt.setData(currentData)
self.connect(playlistContenxt, SIGNAL("triggered()"), self.addToPlaylistAction)
self.musicTable.addAction(playlistContenxt)
```

currentItem.text() is a playlist name thats being fetched from db, as you can see only one function (addToPlaylistAction) receives all triggers from different actions. On my addToPlaylistAction function, how do I determine which menu has been clicked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `QAction.setData` to set some data, so that the slot knows which playlist to add to. Then from the slot you can call `self.sender()` to get the action that triggered the signal, and use `action.data()` to get the data back.

Comment: If you use sender(), just be careful that your function is always called as a slot so that sender() will return something valid.

Answer (score 5):

The correct way is to use [signal mapper](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsignalmapper.html#details): You can assign data to each of the senders and get a signal with that data.

Comment: I found a good example at http://pysnippet.blogspot.com/2010/06/qsignalmapper-at-your-service.html